# postgres cross tab with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE response(session_id int, seconds int, question_id int,
  response varchar(500),file bytea)

INSERT INTO response(session_id, seconds, question_id, response, file)
VALUES 
(652,1459721866,31,0,NULL),(652,1459721866,32,1,NULL),(652,1459721866,33,0,NULL),
(652,1459721866,34,0,NULL),(652,1459721866,35,0,NULL),(652,1459721866,36,0,NULL),
(652,1459721866,37,0,NULL),(652,1459721866,38,0,NULL),(656,1460845066,31,0,NULL),
(656,1460845066,32,0,NULL),(656,1460845066,33,0,NULL),(656,1460845066,34,0,NULL),
(656,1460845066,35,1,NULL),(656,1460845066,36,0,NULL),(656,1460845066,37,0,NULL),
(656,1460845066,38,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,31,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,32,0,NULL),
(657,1463782666,33,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,34,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,35,1,NULL),
(657,1463782666,36,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,37,0,NULL),(657,1463782666,38,0,NULL)
```

`seconds` column is in unix epoch.

It is perfect to do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    crosstab ('select session_id, question_id, response from response order by session_id,question_id') AS aresult (session_id int,
        not_moving varchar(500),
        foot varchar(500),
        bike varchar(500),
        motor varchar(500),
        car varchar(500),
        bus varchar(500),
        metro varchar(500),
        train varchar(500),
        other varchar(500));

session_id  seconds  not_moving foot    bike    motor   car bus metro   train   other
  652    1459721866      0        1      0        0      0    0   0       0     null
  656    1460845066      0        0      0        0      1    0   0       0     null
  657    1460845066      0        0      0        0      1    0   0       0     null
```

But I want row that fall in April 2016 only (first two rows). So I tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    crosstab ('select session_id, question_id, response from response order by session_id,question_id') AS aresult (session_id int,
        not_moving varchar(500),
        foot varchar(500),
        bike varchar(500),
        motor varchar(500),
        car varchar(500),
        bus varchar(500),
        metro varchar(500),
        train varchar(500),
        other varchar(500))
WHERE to_timestamp(seconds) BETWEEN '2016-4-1' AND '2016-4-30'
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "seconds" does not exist
LINE 12: WHERE to_timestamp(seconds) BETWEEN '2016-4-1' AND '2016-4-3...
```

I illustrate it in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lfQf3BSx).

**EDIT**

This didn't work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    crosstab ('select session_id, question_id, response from response WHERE to_timestamp(seconds) BETWEEN '2016-4-1' AND '2016-4-30' order by session_id,question_id') AS aresult (session_id int,
        not_moving varchar(500),
        foot varchar(500),
        bike varchar(500),
        motor varchar(500),
        car varchar(500),
        bus varchar(500),
        metro varchar(500),
        train varchar(500),
        other varchar(500))

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2016"
LINE 2: ...rom response WHERE to_timestamp(seconds) BETWEEN '2016-4-1' ...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Give ```where``` clause inside ```crosstab query``` -   ```crosstab ('select session_id, question_id, response from response [where clause] order by session_id,question_id')```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work, as in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the dates to the query, but you need to escape the single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM
    crosstab ('select session_id, question_id, response 
                from  response WHERE to_timestamp(seconds) BETWEEN ''2016-04-01'' AND ''2016-04-30''
                order by session_id,question_id') AS aresult (session_id int,
        not_moving varchar(500),
        foot varchar(500),
        bike varchar(500),
        motor varchar(500),
        car varchar(500),
        bus varchar(500),
        metro varchar(500),
        train varchar(500),
        other varchar(500))
```

| session_id | not_moving | foot | bike | motor | car | bus | metro | train | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 652 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |
| 656 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/705OCAnz)

Comment: just a follow up to this answer please. In the table (your answer), your show `session_id`, but you are not returning the corresponding `seconds` column values.

Comment: you need to join another subquery where you sum up the seconds for every session_id, within the crosstab it isn't possible